# Swift: textFieldShouldReturn not being called when using multiple textFields

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

`textFieldShouldReturn` is not being called when using more than one `textField`. The `textFields` are set up as numpads and they should save the user input to the variable `textFieldEntry`, but `textFieldShouldReturn` is not being called when the user taps of the `textField`.

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var textFieldOne: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldTwo: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldThree: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldFour: UITextField!

var textFieldEntry: Int?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Looks for single or multiple taps.
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")

    // does not recognise tap when inside view
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false

    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    self.textFieldOne.delegate = self
    self.textFieldTwo.delegate = self
    self.textFieldThree.delegate = self
    self.textFieldFour.delegate = self
}

 func dismissKeyboard() {
//Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
var firstResponder = findActiveResponderFrame(view: view)

var testVar: Int?
if firstResponder!.tag == 0 {
    testVar = Int(textFieldOne.text!)
    print(testVar)
} else if firstResponder!.tag == 1 {
    testVar = Int(textFieldTwo.text!)
    print(testVar)
} else if firstResponder!.tag == 2 {
    testVar = Int(textFieldThree.text!)
    print(testVar)
} else if firstResponder!.tag == 3 {
    testVar = Int(textFieldFour.text!)
    print(testVar)

}
view.endEditing(true)
}


func findActiveResponderFrame(view:UIView)->UIView?{
    if view.isFirstResponder {
        return view
    } else {
        for sub in view.subviews {
            if let subView = sub as? UIView,
                let found = findActiveResponderFrame(view: subView){
                return found
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The should return delegate method is only called when the user types return when the text field is first responder. You've added a tap gesture which ends editing programmatically - this won't call any delegate methods.

You need to restructure your logic, and find which of your text fields is first responder when `dismissKeyboard` is called, and get the values then.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As there is no return key on the IOS numpad, is there another function or work around that saves the user input instead? Would it be using textFieldShouldEndEditing?

Comment: A toolbar with a done button added as an input accessory view is quite common, but that will have the same issue as you have now. If you want to detect changes as they are made to the fields there's the editingChanged action which is called every time the user changes the contents of the field

Comment: I have added the done button to textFields. As you stated, the textFieldShouldReturn is still not being called with that. I just want the value of the textField once the once has dismissed the keyboard, but cant understand how I could achieve that.

Comment: I said in the second paragraph of my answer - when you're dismissing, find out which field is first responder, and get the value there

Comment: I've managed to make it work by assigning each textField a tag and then using functions I've added to my question. Could you have a quick look and see if that looks correct to you? Thanks

Comment: I'd just ask each text view if it is first responder. Don't use tags, especially not zero, because every view has a tag of zero unless you tell it otherwise.

Comment: Ah ok, I overcomplicated it I think. Thanks for your help. Do I mark your answer as correct?

Comment: That's up to you :)